# How to add Events(Birthday&Anniversary dates) to contact manager

Tags: java, android, contacts

I can able to add name,phonenumber and their email id to the contact manager,now i want to add birthday date and anniversary date in the event category to the contact manager,i already write the code but after adding that code in my device those days not showing

```
EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);

                // Getting reference to Mobile EditText 
                EditText etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mobile_phone);

                etbirthday = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                etanniversary  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

                // Getting reference to HomePhone EditText 
                //EditText etHomePhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_home_phone);



                // Getting reference to WorkEmail EditText 
                EditText etWorkEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_work_email); 




                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                          new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                int rawContactID = ops.size();

                // Adding insert operation to operations list 
                // to insert a new raw contact in the table ContactsContract.RawContacts
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert display name in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, etName.getText().toString())
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Mobile Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, etMobile.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());


                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Work Email in the table ContactsContract.Data

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, etWorkEmail.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
                        .build());

                // Event
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Event.START_DATE, etanniversary.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Event.TYPE, Event.TYPE_OTHER)
                        .build());


                System.out.println("anniversarydate"+etanniversary.getText().toString());
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Event.START_DATE, etanniversary.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(Event.TYPE, Event.TYPE_ANNIVERSARY)
                    .build());

                System.out.println("birthdaydate"+etbirthday.getText().toString());
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Event.START_DATE, etbirthday.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(Event.TYPE, Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
                    .build());

                try{
                    // Executing all the insert operations as a single database transaction
                    System.out.println("ops"+ops);
                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contact is successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SharedPreferences prefs1=Addcontact.this.getSharedPreferences("IMS1",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1=prefs1.edit();
                    editor1.putBoolean("isContatcadded",true);
                    editor1.commit();
                    finish();
                }catch (RemoteException e) {                    
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
```